# free memory profiler for .net

Tags: c#, .net, profiler

Someone knows good and free memory profiler for .net? I could find a lot of posts where profilers (such as Eqatec, which is not a memory profiler) are described but there is none where MEMORY profilers are mentioned. I found some including CLR profiler but they doesn't work to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[RedGate's .NET Memory Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/) is the best I have used. It's not free indefinitely, but it is free for 14 days.

Comment: Yes, this one looks nice, I will try it, but given that I am developing non profit open source I don't like idea that I would pay for it

Comment: @Petr: It's not free, but you won't get a good memory profiler for free, since it takes quite a bit of effort to develop one. I'm not sure how to read your comment (I assume you're doing open-source software, not "non-profit"), but if you're actually developing for a 501c3, Red-Gate may have a discount available, or the non-profit may be willing to shell out to support this. Just wanted to mention that.

Comment: Ok, that was why I asked here, to see if there is any, if not good, at least some which actually works. The CLR Profiler (one of these I found so far) only crashes when I try to use it

Comment: @DanielMošmondor: I could swear that it *used to be* a 30 day trial, but I haven't used it in over a year.  Thanks.

Comment: @Petr: It has a free trial as I said, but as others have said, you're simply not going to find an awesome and free memory profiler.  You know what you want, but that's not necessarily what you can get.